# How to use gcov with gcc without the optimization?

Tags: gcc, code-coverage, gcov, lcov, cunit

I have a test code like this:

```
int diff21(int n)
{
    if (n <= 21)
    {
        return 21 - n;
    }
    else
    {
        return (n - 21) * 2;
    }
}
```

and I added the compile flags: `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` to provide coverage data.

I wrote the test code like this:

```
CU_ASSERT(diff21(19) == 2);
```

and I used lcov to generate a html report, and it said the `else` branch's `return (n - 21) * 2` is excuted, so I got a 100% line coverage. **This is not true**

I googled and found that is because of [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Gcov-and-Optimization.html#Gcov-and-Optimization) --- the gcc optimization can eliminate some simple code lines by combining them with other lines, **but how should I generate the coverage data if I'm not supposed to use the `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` flag?**

btw I'm using netbeans and cygwin to do unit tests, I don't think manually calling `gcov` in a makefile or script is good for me.

just for your information, I'm using lcov like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf coverage_report
rm -f app.info

lcov -b . -d . -c -o app.info
mkdir coverage_report
genhtml --legend --highlight -o coverage_report app.info
rm -f app.info
lcov -d . -z
```